# Set object propriety to localStorage

Tags: javascript

I have a obj with more proprieties. How can i set one of the proprieties to local Storage. Just the propriety not the hole Obj (in java). Here is something i tried:

```
function game(){
      this.team_one = "team_one";
      this.team_two = "team_two";
      this.score_home function(val){
      return(typeof(val) === 'undefined' ? : localStorage.myVal = val);
      };
      this.score_away = 0;
}
for(var i=0;i<30;i++){
   game_on.push(new game());
}
game_on[0].score_home(7);
alert(game_on[0].score_home);
```

Comment: 1) java!=javascript; 2) you need to retrieve your object and modify your property ... and update localStorage back

Answer (score 0):

To store data in localStorage you can use:

```
localStorage.setItem(property_name, property_value); //to add property to localStorage
var myProperty = localStorage.getItem(property_name); // to retrieve value.
```

It is also better to check if browser supports localStorage:

```
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Browser supports localStorage and sessionStorage
} else {
    // Browser does not support any of them
}
```